# Returning the response data on ajax success in asynchronous requests

Tags: jquery

```
function save() {
...(these dots means some other operations)
....
.....
dataString= ....(some operations)


var resp;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./add_services.php",
    data: dataString + '&service_id=' + service_id,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        resp = data;
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('ajax processing failed. error is: ' + jqXHR.status + ' ' + jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
return resp;
}
```

Here my intention is that: on ajax success 'data' can be retrieved for use anywhere in the global context,

but the problem synchronous request is that it hangs the browser window for sometimes(waiting for ajax request to finish, i think)

If i do asynchronous requests ( async: true) then save() return value(resp) is nothing.

It would be better if, save() returns the ajax success 'data' with asynchronous requests .
Any Idea ??

Comment: why just call the function which need the `resp` in `success` handler?

Comment: this function ( save ) contains many other operations which are must to build the dataString 
and also many other operations not related to ajax request